# On using beamer's colors in a Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color

For once, my question is short and simple:
How do I use a beamer defined color in a tikz picture.

For instance, as beamer's documentation states, using beamer's colors is done as follows:

```
This text is {\usebeamercolor[fg]{alerted text} alerted}.
The following box uses the fore- and background of frametitles:
{
   \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}
   \colorbox{bg}{Frame Title}
}
```

I would like to use the background color of the titleframe to fill an arrow shape as follows:

```
\usebeamercolor{frametitle}
\tikz
  \node[fill=\color{bg},single arrow] at (0,0) { };
```

Anyone has a clue? I'm being scold by xcolors:

> ! Argument of \XC@col@rlet has an
>   extra }.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TikZ can use the color names provided by `\usebeamercolor` directly, you don't need to pass them to `\color{...}` first. Simply use `color=fg` for the foreground color, `color=bg` for the background, and so on:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello

\begin{tikzpicture}
\frametitle{A Frame}
\usebeamercolor{frametitle}
\tikz
  \fill [fill=fg] (0,0) circle [radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't suspect how simple this was! TY

Comment: This solution works perfect within `beamer` because you can change beamer theme and keep color scheme but if you plan to later write a `beamerarticle` with same code it will fail. `beamerarticle` doesn't know about beamer colors.

Comment: @Ignasi: Good point! For that application you could define a custom command `\newcommand{\usebeamercolor}[1]{\definecolor{fg}{rgb}{<whatever>}}` that sets the required colors.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for lines, I tried: `\draw[fg] (2,2) circle (3cm);` and I get a black circle. Would you know how to solve this?