# Set the background color of mdframed to a color from the Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, mdframed

I want to draw rounded colored text box using mdframed. I'm trying to set background color to green or blue, used in example and theorem environments using `\usebeamercolor`:

```
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt, backgroundcolor=\usebeamercolor[fg]
{block title example}, align=center, userdefinedwidth=4cm, fontcolor=white]
Sequential consistency
\end{mdframed}
```

I got the following error:

```
! Argument of \tikz@swap@args has an
 extra }.
```

Seems like I can't use commands inside `[]`. How could I fix it? When I use just blue!50!black everything works just fine.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt, backgroundcolor=\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title example}, align=center, userdefinedwidth=4cm, fontcolor=white]   %\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title example}
Sequential consistency
\end{mdframed}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similarly to [On using beamer's colors in a Tikz picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60518/on-using-beamers-colors-in-a-tikz-picture#60521) one could proceed as follows:

- first declare the desired color with `\usebeamercolor{block title example}`
- then use it with `block title example.fg` (or with `.bg` for the background).

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\usebeamercolor{block title example}
\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=5pt, backgroundcolor=block title example.fg, align=center, userdefinedwidth=4cm, fontcolor=white]  
Sequential consistency
\end{mdframed}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Or `backgroundcolor=fg` which has the same effect.

Comment: Sorry for repetition, I searched for mdframed and beamer, should have searched for an error. Thanks!

Comment: @bloodworks: yes it works too, but I prefer this syntax for future readability (when I came back to old documents just reading `fg` says almost nothing in case you use several different colors).