# Accessing colors defined by a beamer color theme for a standalone tikzpicture

Tags: beamer, color, standalone

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60518/8425).

I use the `standalone` documentclass to externalize my `tikzpicture`s. Now, I want to include it in a beamer presentation with its color theme set to, say,  `default`. I'd like that the colors I use in the standalone `tikzpicture` match those defined in the presentation (`structure`, `normal text.fg`, `example text.fg`, etc). How can I do?

Ideally, I'd like something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ImportColorDefinitionsFromBeamerColorTheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[structure.fg] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw[palette primary.fg] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(notice that `palette primary.fg` won't work in beamer either, one need to use `\usebeamercolor[fg]{palette primary}` and I don't know how to do it with `tikz`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,beamer]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[structure.fg] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \usebeamercolor{palette primary}
  \draw[fg] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Minor issue though: the resulting bounding box fits the frame (IIUC) and no more the `tikzpicture`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding crop=true to the accepted answer makes the bounding box fit the tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass[tikz,beamer,crop=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[structure.fg] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \usebeamercolor{palette primary}
  \draw[fg] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/232573)