# Get access to beamer palette for tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I can't get the solution proposed here to work: [Accessing colors defined by a beamer color theme for a standalone tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152984/accessing-colors-defined-by-a-beamer-color-theme-for-a-standalone-tikzpicture)

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{tikz}%Mind map
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees} %Mind map
\usepackage{media9,multimedia,comment,booktabs,datetime}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Literature Review}
%\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=2}}
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{
\hspace{50pt}\begin{tikzpicture}
 %\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\Large,level distance=8cm]
    \path[mindmap,concept color=DeepSkyBlue4,text=white,font=\sf\bf,text width=5cm,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=60},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=4cm},]

        node[concept] {Learning}[clockwise from=0]
        child[concept color=DeepSkyBlue4] {
            node[concept] {practical}[clockwise from=90]
            child { node[concept] {algorithms} [clockwise from=40]
            child { node[concept] {databases} }
            child { node[concept] {WWW} }}
            child { node[concept] {data structures} }
        }  
        child[concept color=red,text=black] {
            node[concept] {applied}[clockwise from=360]
            child { node[concept,level distance=16cm,sibling angle=60] {databases} }
        }
        child[concept color=red,text=black] { 
            node[concept] {technical} 
        }
        child[concept color=red,text=black] { 
            node[concept,text width=2cm] {theoretical} 
        };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I replace `red` above with whatever is set by the selected theme (or customized with `\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10}`? I want to do this for various tikzpicture, pgfplots etc.

Comment: Have a look to [How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66465/13304)

Comment: This is sort of a dirty trick to redefine `red` colour itself, highly unrecommended (three lines of code):
\colorlet{myred}{red} % store it  
\colorlet{red}{green} % change it  
%\colorlet{red}{myred} % get it back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why but some `beamer` colors are available (like `structure.fg`) and some others not. But you can always *define* your own colors based on beamer theme ones. This way, when you change beamer theme, all colors will change.

After

```
\usebeamercolor{block title alerted}
\colorlet{color1}{bg}
```

`color1` will be equal to `block title alerted.bg` color. You can repeat this lines to *define* more colors. Next code shows an example with this solution.

Another solution is provided by Claudio Fiandrino in [How to get actual values of colour theme colours in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66475/1952) where a newcommand `\ccft` (Create color from template) is used to define *normal* colors based on *beamer* ones.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false},xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{tikz}%Mind map
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees} %Mind map
\usepackage{media9,multimedia,comment,booktabs,datetime}

\usebeamercolor{block title alerted}
\colorlet{color1}{bg}
\usebeamercolor{block body}
\colorlet{color2}{bg}
\colorlet{color3}{bg!30!color1}

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=red,bg=black!10}
\usebeamercolor{palette tertiary}
\colorlet{color4}{bg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Literature Review}
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{
\hspace{50pt}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[mindmap,
        concept color=structure.fg,
        text=white,font=\sf\bf,text width=5cm,
       level 1/.append style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=60},
       level 2/.append style={level distance=4cm},]

       node[concept] {Learning}[clockwise from=0]
       child[concept color=color1] {
            node[concept] {practical}[clockwise from=90]
            child { node[concept, concept color=color2] {algorithms} [clockwise from=40]
            child { node[concept] {databases} }
            child { node[concept] {WWW} }}
            child { node[concept] {data structures} }
        }  
        child[concept color=color3,text=black] {
            node[concept] {applied}[clockwise from=360]
            child { node[concept,level distance=16cm,sibling angle=60] {databases} }
        }
        child[concept color=color4,text=black] { 
            node[concept] {technical} 
        }
        child[concept color=color4!30!black, text=white] { 
            node[concept,text width=2cm] {theoretical} 
        };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Implicitly, this is the same trick my `\ccft` (Create Color From Template) is doing in the linked answer.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You're right! After a second lecture I've understood it. I've included a reference to your code.