# Beamer: Change Structure Color in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color

Why doesn't the following MWE change the color of the latter fill to red? How to fix?

Background: I am changing the structure color for my example frames and want all the tikzpictures within to use colors based on the structure color.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My Default Structure Color Rectangle}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=structure] rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}

\begin{frame}{My Red Rectangle}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=structure] rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to set `\usebeamercolor` before actually use it, and you should specify `structure.fg`. See [Accessing colors defined by a beamer color theme for a standalone tikzpicture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152984/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino But how could `fill=structure` not give an error?

Comment: @Symbol1: `structure` is simply a color name, and TikZ can use such names (see [On using beamer's colors in a Tikz picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60518/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino OK, I found it. In `beamerbasecolor.sty` there is `\colorlet{structure}{structure.fg}`. This looks pretty unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set `\usebeamercolor` before actually use it. In addition you should specify `.fg` while using the color, i.e. `structure.fg`. This is because while setting `\usebeamercolor` you also have access to `structure.bg`, which is a different color.

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{My Default Structure Color Rectangle}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=structure] rectangle (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}

    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}

    \begin{frame}{My Red Rectangle}
    \usebeamercolor{structure}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=structure.fg] rectangle (2,2);
        \draw (4,0) [fill=structure.bg] rectangle+ (2,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps change the first fill from `structure` to `structure.fg` too?

Comment: @Mappi: Yes, you should definitely do it.