# Defining global styles, using tikzset and usebeamercolor

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, themes

I am defining a corporate design `beamer` template.

Actually, I have defined some given colors in the `beamercolorthemeCD.sty` file.  (Next step will be, to define some font templates via `beamerfontthemeCD.sty`.  Maybe I will face the same problem, as with the colors?)

I am using `tikzpictures` to place the different CD elements onto my slides.  To make it most efficient  and simple, I defined some global TikZ styles by `\tikzset`...

Now I want to combine the beamer template definitions with the TikZ styles, e.g. I want to use a special color given in the `beamercolorthemeCD.sty` on some TikZ drawn elements using the `\tikzset` defining a style.

This definition does not work:

```tex
%% Define the color, 
\setbeamercolor{dark decoration}{fg=black}

%% Use that color in this TikZ style
\tikzset{%
   dark/.style={%
      line width=\rulerwidth,
      color={\usebeamercolor{dark decoration}},
   }%
}%
```

LaTeX gives an error

> Missing \endcsname inserted.

and also

> Paragraph ended before \XC@col@rlet was complete.

I found a [similiar question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60518/on-using-beamers-colors-in-a-tikz-picture), stating, that you can use the color of the **actual** beamer template.

But in my case, the decoration elements are used in different locations (e.g. `headline`, `footline` and other templates), where different foreground and background colors are used.  (The decoration elements should not change the color in the different templates/environments.)

Also: at the time, when the TikZ styles are defined, there is no actual template in effect, so just saying `color=fg`, as the solving answer suggests, does not work in my case.

Is there a way, to globally define the TikZ style colors using a beamer color template?

Here is an MWE to play with

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Some ordinary title}
\author{I. T. Sme, A. Gain}
\date{Later On}

\setbeamercolor{dark decoration}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{light decoration}{fg=grey}

\tikzset{%
  dark/.style={%
    line width=1pt,
    % This doesn't work :(
    color={\usebeamercolor{dark decoration}},
  }%
}%
      
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[dark] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the color at least once to have it available in `xcolor` format. This works:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Some ordinary title}
\author{I. T. Sme, A. Gain}
\date{Later On}

\setbeamercolor{dark decoration}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{light decoration}{fg=grey}

\tikzset{%
  dark/.style={%
    line width=1pt,
    % This doesn't work :( unless you use the color before!
    color=dark decoration.fg,
  }%
}%
      
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{dark decoration}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[dark] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am on a cellphone now, and it's too painful to check what happens exactly - the blank line after the `\begin{frame}` is necessary. Tomorrow I'll adjust it...

Comment: Wow.  Easy solution.  THANK YOU.

Comment: I used a `\AtBeginDocument{\usebeamercolor{dark decoration}\tkizset{...` and it worked charmingly!  Even without blank lines at `\begin{frame}`.